# Exe file compiled by pyinstaller can't execute on AIX 7.1

Tags: pyinstaller, aix

I'm trying to compile exe file with pyinstaller on AIX 7.1, but the exe file can't execute, below is my screenshot of error message.

[image][image]

The python3 version is 3.9.6, Aix is 7.1 64-bits, pyinstaller is 6.2.0.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I degrade the version of pyinstaller from 6.2.0 to 4.10, and the issue solved.